# return Json will redirects to another view when Url specified

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-4

When you do return Json(...) you are specifically telling MVC not to use a view, and to serve serialized JSON data. Your browser opens a download dialog because it doesn't know what to do with this data.

i got the above information from below link

[How to return Json object from MVC controller to view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15196528/how-to-return-json-object-from-mvc-controller-to-view)

when i give this below code in some action result

```
return Json(new { Url = "sep/employee"}
```

whether it will redirect to specified action  ? how it redirects to the URl ?

for this case why i cant use  return RedirectToAction("sep/employee").

how **return Json** code redirects to action which specified in the Url.

ex:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
................................

return Json(new { Url = "sep/employee"}
}

public ActionResult employee()
{
....................
}
```

what is the difference b/s redirectaction and return Json

Comment: What does your view look like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You return the following line to an `ajax` `success` call

```
return Json(new { Url = "sep/employee"});
```

you then need to specify where to redirect to the new page

```
success: function(result) {
        window.location.href=result.Url;
    }
```

Comment: return Json(new { Url = "sep/employee"} -> it automatically redirects to employee action that works fine. i am asking how it is working and what is the difference between redirectaction

Comment: are u calling index method from ajax call, please post success call for that ajax

Comment: am not calling index from ajax call.its inital page load

Comment: but i have tested it doesnt redirects to action only returns {"Url":"Home/Index"} on page in my case

Comment: Thank you  i got it.for me also not working until i used your code.thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

`RedirectToAction` simply returns 302 code to your browser with URL telling where the browser should redirect to. The browser immediately makes yet another call to the server to that URL obtained from redirection response.

RedirectToAction internals are:

1. Construct redirection url from parameters passed to `RedirectToAction`
2. Return new `RedirectToRouteResult`
3. In `ExecuteResult` of `RedirectToRouteResult` you can find the following line:

   context.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(destinationUrl, endResponse: false);

which is merely returning 302 with redirection URL. More info - look at source code [here](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/RedirectToRouteResult.cs).

Returning JSON data simply returns JSON serialized object to your browser. Is not meant to do any redirect. To consume such a result you will likely call the server using `$.ajax`:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'sep/employee',
    type: 'POST'
    success: function(result) {
        // handle the result from the server, i.e. process returned JSON data
    }
});
```

`ExecuteResult` of `JsonResult` just serializes passed CLR object to the response stream, which lands in your browser after response is fully received. Then you can handle such response in JavaScript code.

**EDIT:**

You of course can mimic 302 redirection by returning Json like

```
return Json(new { Url = "redirectionUrl"}
```

and at client side handle it like

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'sep/employee',
    type: 'POST'
    success: function(result) {
        // mimic the 302 redirection
        windows.location.href = result.Url
    }
});
```

although IMHO it should be avoided since you reinvent MVC infrastructure and enlarge your code base.

Comment: no.it is redirected to specified action.i am asking how it is working ? what is the difference between redirectaction

Comment: Answer edited. An 'action' is transformed to URL using passed args (controller name, action name, route data, ...)

Answer (score 1):

**whether it will redirect to specified action ? how it redirects to the URl ?**

I assume you mean to ask, *"will it redirect to specified action? how will it redirect the the URI?"*

To answer your question: How it redirects to the URL?

In your example it will redirect to the URL, if you made the HTTP request as AJAX and that you will explicitly handle the resulting HTTP response to **actually** redirect to the URL that you received. So your view should have something like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '{your controller}/index',
  type: 'GET'
  success: function(url) {
    // write code to redirect to the URL
    // example: 
    //   window.navigate(url)
  }
});
```

If your view does not have anything that, then it will not redirect. You did not post your view, so I am assuming it just a normal page load.

Your next question, what is the difference b/s redirection and return Json?

If you really just want to redirect then do RedirectToAction from your controller, that is exactly what it is for. You can do the same effect using AJAX and JSON to be able to redirect, but AJAX and JSON serves a much wider purpose than just redirecting and in most cases (unless you have very good reasons) you probably will not want replace RedirectToAction with that approach.