# How to pass LIST to view as JSON in MVC asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net-mvc

I need to pass this list to my view:
[image]

But in this format:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "FIRST_NAME": "Robert",
      "LAST_NAME": "Meczybula",
      "ID": 12421
       ...
     },
...
]}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return Json object from MVC controller to view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15196528/how-to-return-json-object-from-mvc-controller-to-view)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you want to transform your list to the desired data contract.  Linq is good for this:

```
var transform = new
    {
        data = data.Select(x => 
            new {
                x.FIRST_NAME,
                x.LAST_NAME,
                ...
            }),
        ...
    };
```

Then just serialize and return the transform object.